# Xamarin.forms putting default text in editor class on multiple lines

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Essentially, I want to put multiple lines of text in one Editor class, a template of sorts.

I have tried just putting the plaintext of what I want in but it comes out in one line.

```
<Editor 

Text="
Dear Blank,
How are you today?
I'm fine if you were wondering" />
```

I would like the text entry to have

```
Dear Blank,
How are you today?
I'm fine if you were wondering
```

But it comes out as

```
Dear Blank, How are you today? I'm fine if you were wondering
```

In the text entry box/ editor class in my app.

Comment: Try to set `VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"` or `HeightRequest`

Answer (score 1):

as

```
\r, CR: &#13;
\n, LF: &#10;
```

The easiest way you could change your text like this:

```
<Editor 
     Text="Dear Blank,&#10;How are you today?&#10;I'm fine if you were wondering"/>
```

add `&#10;` behind the string which you want